# Django - A link that will update database row before leaving site

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new to Python development and working on a specific project. I have a list of 'action items' that people can 'claim'. So I created a Model that has all of the information about the action item, including a BooleanField called `is_claimed` which is defaulted to False.

I'm printing out all of the action items in a table, of which the last column is a link to an external site (which is also a URLField in my model).

I want to have that last table cell be something like this:

```
<a href="{{ action_item.url }}">Claim and Complete Action Item</a>
```

When someone clicks that URL, I need to update the database to show `is_claimed=True`.

Any ideas or help? Sorry if this question is too simplistic. Learning a lot but need some expert help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your link tags point to this view, which sets  `is_claimed` on the model and then redirects to the foreign URL.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import ActionItem


def link_counter(request, action_id):
    # Retrieve the clicked item
    action_item = ActionItem.objects.get(pk=action_id)
    # Set 'is_claimed' to true
    action_item.is_claimed = True
    action_item.save()

    # Redirect the user, to the url associated with the 'action_item'
    return redirect(action_item.url)
```

Your anchor tags will look like this:

`<a href="{% url 'link_counter' action_item.id %}">Claim and Complete Action Item</a>`

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly (but allowed me to try and figure out the `urlpatterns` without asking another question. But now works flawlessly.